# why are my confusion matrices getting cut off?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, spyder

When I use `sns.heatmap(data)` my results always get cutoff.

[image: example of cut off matrices]

The code I used to make this is:

```
sns.heatmap(pd.DataFrame([[.2, .2, .3], 
                          [.1, .7, .9],
                          [.9, .6, .2]], 
                         columns = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3'],
                         index = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']), 
            robust = True, annot = True)
```

I am using spyder 4.0.1, any idea whats going on?

Comment: What is your matplotlib's version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading matplotlib to the last version (3.1.3) should solve the issue:

`conda update matplotlib`

if you're using Anaconda or

`pip install -U matplotlib`

otherwise, and you should get:

[image]

Comment: Worked great! Thanks!